# Creating Packet in GEM5 in Garnet Standalone

Tags: networking, cpu-architecture, router, packet, gem5

does anyone knows how to create a new Packet in Garnet Standalone in GEM5 and send it from desired router to desired location. Suppose I want to create a Packet and I want to send it from router id 5 to router id 10.

I've tried some implementation in the networkinterface.cc, packet.cc and some other files but I'm not getting the exact way to create a packet and send it to the network. I'm able to create a flit and send it to network to the required location but not able to send the packet.